# How to create a simple Spring Boot app with GraphQL and gRPC?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, graphql, grpc

I'd like to see a simple, minimal Spring Boot app with gRPC and GraphQL integration, but I haven't found any example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on [github](https://github.com/kijanowski/grpc-graphql-springboot) for both graphicQL and gRPC

And here is a [blog page](https://blog.softwaremill.com/take-spring-boot-graphql-and-grpc-micro-services-solve-the-n-1-query-issue-with-dataloader-c2fec7b43517) for walk throw this example , Step by step.